# How to include a Wordpress Shortcode in your Code, not in the Posts Section

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I want to insert a hardcoded short code in my code, and not from the usual Text Editor we usually use.

Basically I want this to add a gallery, and the user doesn't need to change the shortcode from the CMS so I will be hardcoding this.

How would I need to do this, I tried to just post it in my .php file but it doesn't work.

This is the code I want to add:

[jj-ngg-jquery-slider gallery="1" width="866" height="341" ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the trick to include in `.php` files:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[jj-ngg-jquery-slider gallery="1" width="866" height="341"]'); ?>
```

Comment: Reference material: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

Answer (score 2):

shortcodes were created to include in post or pages. I could be wrong but wordpress checks the input of a post and if it finds a shortcode it will replace it with the html. I don't think it will work if you add shortcodes in your .php file because wordpress doesn't look for shortcodes in your php files

You could just create a function in functions.php to generate the html you need. Then you just call that function within your theme .php file. That's how most plugins are made. Shortcode for post & pages and function in the php files.

example:

```
<?php echo myGallery(array('gallery'=>1, 'width'=>866, 'height' => 341); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Krike for your answer, so basically I would need to create a function and then call the function from that line you gave me. I have little knowledge of PHP to be honest I don't know what I'll need to do this.

Comment: If you want to get your hands dirty with wordpress, php & functions you will have to learn a bit about php (here's a good tutorial serie -> http://blog.themeforest.net/screencasts/diving-into-php-video-series/). The example I gave you above is how you call the function and pass parameters to it to make it dynamic.

Comment: Thanks very much, I know Java, so I should understand that without much problems.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this method ? do_shortcode($content)

I've seen it on http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API